# How bind vue json schema and element-ui select?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jsonschema

I can not understand how I can link the vue-json-scheme and the element-ui select.
[example](https://github.com/formschema/elementui/tree/master/src)

```
FormSchema.setComponent('select', 'el-select')

"lists": {
      "type": "string",
      "title": "List",
      "enum": ["Daily New", "Promotion"],
      "attrs": {
        "placeholder": "Select your list subscription",
        "title": "Please select your list subscription"
      }
    },
```

so everything works fine, but only if these data are static.
And if I need to make a Rest request? Help me to understand.
How do I send a request to Api when I click on a select?

Comment: It's not designed for dynamic data. You will need to create your own solution for this.

Comment: @Relequestual https://github.com/vue-generators/vue-form-generator , will not work?

Comment: To make http requests you'll need something like `axios`. About data, you need to understand that Vue itself doesn't have anything proper to data manipulation, you'll need something like `Vuex`.

Comment: It will depend on if the library has some way to do what you want or not. Forms are not a part of JSON Schema. You'll need to create your own code for dynamically loading in data for a select box. I don't think you want to generate these forms from a JSON Schema.

Comment: @Relequestual I'm just understanding this, can you push me?